# How to access specific column in NSArray using Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS programming. I'm trying to bind the specific field from the objects in an array to a `UITableView`. Here's my code:

```
NSArray *personInfo; //contains a record with fields: name, address, email

personInfo = [[PersonDatabase database] getAllPersons]; //pulling the record into array
```

From there, I'm trying to get the field "name" from my array.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [personInfo objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] retain]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "columns" in the array? What objects are in the array? Are they NSDictionaries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems you have objects in your array, what you may be looking for is the `-[NSArray valueForKey:]` method ([documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)).

For example:

```
NSArray *names = [personInfo valueForKey:@"name"];
```

This should return you an array containing all of the names in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a 2D Array?. If so you'll need to call objectAtIndex: twice on it in a nested call, but since you're new I'd suggest breaking down to a few lines so you can see more clearly what is happening.

Also, theres heaps of good code snippets on google for dealing with NSArray and table view.

Comment: i've already created my array using dis code "personInfo = [[PersonDatabase database] getAllPersons];" which intializethe personinInfo array variable. may goal is to pull a specific column in an array so i can bind it into my tableview cell. the personInfo array has 3 columns (name,addres,email) and 5 records. how do i pull the name column in the array? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check that if you delcare your array in **@interface** file as
//////.h

```
NSArray *personInfo;
@property(nonatomic ,retain) NSArray personInfo;
```

and then

in **@implementation** file 
add this line

```
@synthesize personInfo;
```

hope it works

Comment: i've already declared all this.. may only problem is how to i access the specific columns in the array? 

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [personInfo objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] retain] --> how to assign the specific columns in the array to my cell??